# Write message from IRC channel into a file with PircBotX

Tags: java, event-handling, irc

Hello I am pretty new with Java but I have fiddled with a bit.

This time I am trying to make a bot for my Twitch channel that I can configure on my own, like making a raffle and some other independent stuff.

I am using a library to connect with the Twitch IRC called PircBotX: https://code.google.com/p/pircbotx/ and I have some understanding on how to answer back with ListenerAdapter like so:

```
public class Commands extends ListenerAdapter {
    public void onMessage(MessageEvent event) {
        if (event.getMessage().equals("!commands")) {
            event.respond("Available user commands: !topic, !faq, !youtube, !twitter, !schedule, !time");
        }
    }
}
```

But in this particular listener I am trying to return a message when a person does:

```
!topic newtopic
```

In this instance you need to get the "newtopic" string.

I don't know if there is a way to save the topic in the Twitch API so I just write it in my own file.

I am thinking it might look like this:

```
newText = event.getMessage.?????

if (event.getMessage().equals("!topic " + newText)) {

    if (event.getChannel().isOp(event.getUser())) {

        try (BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("topic.txt"))) {
            br.write(newText);
            br.close();
            event.getChannel().send().message("Topic: " + newText);
        }
    }

    else {
        event.respond("Only mods can change the topic");
    }
}
```

Am I doing it wrong?

I have looked through the API and I just don't understand how it works. Can anyone help?

Comment: Problem solved. I figured it out with a little help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might want to answer my own question for people that might get into a similar dilemma.

This is how you declare the string, really easy:

```
String newText = event.getMessage().substring(("!topic ").length());
```

I remember using substring() many times. Just a little stupid mistake.

For more info on it check here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm